# How to hide and preset label jquery css

Tags: jquery, radio-button

How can I in jquery change the following code so that when someone selects Archived (id = radio3), Option 2 is hidden and Option 1 (id = radio5) is selected, is the Option's back ground is changed ?

Even the alert isn't working ?

```
$("input[@name='radios2']").change(function(){
  alert("12");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aPsE4/4/

Comment: There's no `</br>` and you don't need `@` in front of `name`. Also your `for` attributes are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `</br>`, instead use CSS margins, and you don't need `@` in front of `name`. Also your `<label>`'s `for` attributes are wrong.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input[name='radios']").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "true") {
      $("label[for='radio5']").addClass("hidden");
      $("#radio4").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("label[for='radio5']").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#radio4, #radio5").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
  $("input[name='radios2']").change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

```css
.radio-toolbar {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.radio-toolbar label.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="false">
  <label for="radio2">Open</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="true">
  <label for="radio3">Archived</label>
</div>

<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios2" value="false">
  <label for="radio4">Option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="radios2" value="true">
  <label for="radio5">Option 2</label>
</div>
```

**Update and answers to your comments:**

> Thanks, how can I add the code above so I can try once Archived is selected, to hide "Option 2" and have "Option 1" shown as selected ?

Use the following code:

```
$("input[name='radios']").change(function() {
  if (this.value == "true") {
    $("label[for='radio5']").addClass("hidden");
    $("#radio4").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("label[for='radio5']").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#radio4, #radio5").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

> There is just a Run code snippet , no edit ?

Edit Snippet will come if you own the post. Example, try editing your question and adding a snippet using Ctrl + M.

Comment: Thanks, how can I add the code above so I can try once Archived is selected, to hide "Option 2" and have "Option 1" shown as selected ? There is just a Run code snippet , no edit ?

Comment: @Web_Developer Updated the answer. Just add the next few lines. It's done.

Comment: @Web_Developer Edit Snippet will come if you own the post. Example, try editing your question and adding a snippet using Ctrl + M.

Comment: Thanks, Option 2 does disappear when Archived is chosen, but Option 1 still isn't selected as there is only 1 option, no need to press it ?

Comment: Ohhh... Okay. Updated it.

Comment: Yes, that is it, thanks ! How can I post it as answered ?